# What about traffic in the schema: blobs (central us)---> adf copy activity (western us) ---> azure dwh (central us)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I wanna load a telemetry data with ADF from Azure Blob Storage to Azure DWH.

Azure Blob Storage Account is placed in Central US

Azure DWH is placed in Central US

But ADF is available in West US and East US.

Looks like i will have the schema:

blob storage (central us)---> adf copy activity (western us) ---> azure dwh (central us)

**Will i be charged for the traffic between regions in the case above?**

**Where will the copy activity executed in Central US or in West US?**

I have read the doc below

[The service automatically chooses the optimal region to perform the data movement. This region is usually the one closest to the sink data store.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-data-movement-activities)

but i'm not sure for 100% what they actually mean:

this: blob storage (central us)---> adf copy activity (**western us**) ---> azure dwh (central us)

or

this: blob storage (central us)---> adf copy activity (**central us**) ---> azure dwh (central us)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this link](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/data-factory/data-factory-data-movement-activities.md), there is a table that outlines where the copy activity actually happens. In your specific example it should all happen in Central US and you should not be charged egress charges.